# Which API can get the display brightness?

Tags: uwp, win-universal-app, display

I found:

```
BrightnessOverride bo = BrightnessOverride.GetDefaultForSystem();
bo.BrightnessLevel();
```

may related to brightness read. But when I run the code, it got an exception says: "Access denied". The API document say it need a systemManagement capability. I tried create a Package.appxmanifest file and write below code in it. But the visual studio warn that systemManagement is not permitted argument for it.

Anyone knows why? Or other advice to fetch display brightness? thanks.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2010/manifest">
  <Identity Name=""
            Version=""
            Publisher="" />
  <Properties>
    <DisplayName></DisplayName>
    <PublisherDisplayName></PublisherDisplayName>
    <Logo></Logo>
  </Properties>
  <Prerequisites>
    <OSMinVersion></OSMinVersion>
    <OSMaxVersionTested></OSMaxVersionTested>
  </Prerequisites>
  <Resources>
    <Resource Language="" />
  </Resources>
  <Capabilities>
    <Capability Name="systemManagement"/>
  </Capabilities>
  <Applications>
    <Application Id="" StartPage="">
      <VisualElements DisplayName="" Description=""
           Logo="" SmallLogo=""
           ForegroundText="" BackgroundColor="">
        <SplashScreen Image="" />
      </VisualElements>
    </Application>
  </Applications>
</Package>
```

Comment: Don't ask for control of system brightness. Use `GetForCurrentView` to get app brightness, and then ask for the current `BrightnessLevel` for your app.

Comment: As mentioned below, this capability is for IoT only. If you do want this feature, you have to use `<iot:Capability Name="systemManagement" />` with `xmlns:iot="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/iot/windows10"` in the root Package node

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the *user*, instead of the app, can adjust the brightness of the display. Auto-adjust brightness is a task of the system. Oh, although not a strong reason, remember that UWP can run on devices *without* a display.

So `UWP` does not provide this functionality (getting current brightness reading of the display).

As to why `BrightnessOverride` requires **systemManagement** capability, I don't quite understand. After all, this overriding is per-application, means only the app itself is affected.

**Edit:**

As Raymond pointed out in his comment, this API can control per-application brightness as well as system brightness.

Setting display brightness ***is*** basic system administration, so it needs the capability to be declared.

Comment: `BrightnessOverride.GetDefaultForSystem()` gives you the control over the system brightness, not app brightness. That's why it requires systemManagement capability. (Also, systemManagement capability is legal only on IoT systems.)

Comment: The documentation is misleading. BrightnessOverride can control either per-app brightness (via `GetForCurrentView`) or system brightness (via `GetDefaultForSystem`). The main use is per-app brightness, so that's what the documentation focuses on. I'll see what I can do to get things clarified.

Comment: @RaymondChen thanks for clarification, Raymond, I have edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: @FaymondChen I just want to get the system brightness. and I saw there is  a property "brightness" has only read capability. I don't think this  class is design for modification.